# Unwanted polyline extension when zoom in and disappears on zoom out on android Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I connected map locations using Polyline API. It creates polyline properly.But sometimes unwanted polyline extended when zoom in and disappears on zoom out.

**My code:**

```
locations.clear();
            for(int i=0;i<maplatitude.size();i++)
            {
                locations.add(new LatLng(maplatitude.get(i), maplongitude.get(i)));
            }

            PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            rectOptions.addAll(locations);

            // Get back the mutable Polyline
            Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);

            for(int i=0;i<maplatitude.size();i++)
            {
                //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(maplatitude.get(i), maplongitude.get(i))).title(name).snippet(mapdate.get(i)+"\n"+maptime.get(i)));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(maplatitude.get(i), maplongitude.get(i))).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)).title(String.valueOf(i)));
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this: it's a bug from Google.  We must filter some close points within 1 or 2 meters.

[Polylines appearing on map where they shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422314/polylines-appearing-on-map-where-they-shouldnt)