# Android google-maps v2 polyline wrong

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, google-polyline

I am recording coordinated inside onLocationChanged() and drawing polylines between each to create the route taken by the user. But sometimes the polylines extend to infinity and off the screen [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuTHF.png). They disappear at certain zoom levels but reappear when you zoom back in. Below is the code used:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(driver));
            routePoints.add(driver); // driver is location object
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            polylineOptions.addAll(routePoints);
            map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422314/polylines-appearing-on-map-where-they-shouldnt try to filter the lines that are close to each others.

Comment: I have tried filtering them checking the distance between them using distanceTo() function, this has still not solved the problem.